# Strptime - text format contains written month names

Tags: python, date, datetime, calendar, strptime

Is it possible to use `strptime` with text like this: `Wed 29th Jul 13:02:30`. The point is that I want to have proper format to compare dates.

So I'm looking for something like:

```
datetime.strptime(' '.join(date.split(' ')[1:]), "%d-%m-%h:%m:%s")
```

Is it possible? If not, what is the best option how to do that?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior? You can do the abbreviated weekday, the `'th'` might be trickier...

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` to remove any rd, nd, st, and th then parse normally:

```
s = "Wed 29th Jul 13:02:30"

from datetime import datetime
import  re
dte = datetime.strptime(re.sub("rd|nd|st|th","",s), "%a %d %b %H:%M:%S")
```

You could also use [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) to do the work for you :

```
 s= "Wed 29th Jul 13:02:30"
 from dateutil import parser

 print(parser.parse(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the "th", "st" and "nd" on the date.

Then use:

```
datetime.strptime("Wed 29 Jul 13:02:30", "%a %d %b %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: With either string.replace or re library I suppose.

Comment: That is about 90 percent of the question, the OP can read the docs to get the format specifiers, this is a comment not an answer